# How can I remove notification circle on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to remove my .badge-alert that is being set on click, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do this. I think I know why it's happening, every time the cookieData is <= jsonDate, it sets it again. So even on click it's not removing it. I've tried moving things around to no avail. I've gotten close, on click it will remove everything, but I don't want to remove the .stakebox-container, only the badge-alert.

```
    if (!Cookies.get('inbox')){
    Cookies.set('inbox', 2018030, { expires: 9000000 });
};
var cookieDate = Cookies.get('inbox');
console.log(cookieDate);

$.each(stakeBox, function(i, stakeBoxData){
    var jsonDate = stakeBoxData.data_change_date;
    var winLoss = stakeBoxData.win;
    var points = stakeBoxData.amount_stakebox;
    var winLoss = stakeBoxData.win;
    var id = stakeBoxData.id;
    var homeTeam = stakeBoxData.home_team;
    var awayTeam = stakeBoxData.away_team

    if(cookieDate <= jsonDate){
        // this counts the true and false JSON data;

        console.log(jsonDate);

        var count = i + 1 ;

        $('.badge-alert').text(count);

        $('.stakebox-container').append('\
            <div id="'+ id +'" class="stakebox-message-container">\
                <div class="stakebox-icon"></div>\
                <div class="stakebox-game"><h5>' + awayTeam + ' at ' + homeTeam +'</h5></div>\
                <div class="stakebox-points"><h5>'+ points +'</h5></div>\
            </div>\
        ');
        if (winLoss === true){
        $('.stakebox-icon').last().append('<i class="far fa-smile face"></i>');
        $('.stakebox-message-container').last().css('background', '#35c3ad');
        } else if (winLoss === false) {
            $('.stakebox-message-container').last().css('background', '#a20000');
            $('.stakebox-icon').last().append('<i class="far fa-frown face"></i>');
        };

    } else {
    }
});
$('#stakebox').click(function(){
    var cookieValue = Cookies.get('inbox');
    Cookies.remove('inbox');
    Cookies.set('inbox', 20180303, { expires: 9000000 });
    $('.badge-alert').remove();
 });
```

Comment: is the stakebox click removing badge-alert once and then never again, or is it never removing even the first time?

Comment: @Emil it's removing it then putting it back on when the browser goes to the other page

Comment: You need to check the cookie on page load, then, not just on the click event.

Comment: @DanielBeck $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

Something like that?

Comment: I'm honestly not following the logic behind what is supposed to cause the badge to appear or disappear -- it looks like you always set the same cookie value and expiration no matter what happens, which seems less than useful. But in general, yes; whatever condition causes the badge to disappear, you should check for that condition  on page load as well as on user click; and when the user clicks you should set a condition that won't cause the badge to immediately reappear.